# Security bridge on bitcoin-qt walletpassphrase

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-security

Is it safe to use walletpassphrase with bitcoin-qt rpc call ?
I can think of a security problem, suppose hacker was able to insert some kind of program that call each second to the wallet with sendToAddress and the hacker bitcoin address, now he will get a lock response each time until the call will execute on the timespan the wallet is unlocked. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wallet passphrase protects against an attacker who has access to your *disk* but not the rest of your system.

If someone has access to your bitcoind through RPC, you need to protect by setting an RPC password, not a wallet encryption password.

Comment: But can't the hacker use some kind of listener (man in the middle attack) on that port and see the Credentials in the post ?

Comment: Yes, but if your attacker can access your local machine, you have far bigger problems. He could replace your bitcoind...